# Hibernate - referencing abstract entity defined with <union-subclass>

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, polymorphic-associations

I have an abstract entity `A` which has several `union-subclass`es. `A.id` generator was set to `hilo` (`identity` does not work). The other entity, `B` references this `A` entity as one-to-many (say, `B.setOfA`). Now if I try to persist an instance of `B` I get the following SQL error:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: A
```

That's understandable since A doesn't generate any DDL during `hbm2ddl`. But I need to do exactly that -- polymorphic reference using abstract entity. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Here is a similar mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584465/hibernate-union-subclass-table-per-concrete-class-mapping-generator-of-increm